# Can "increased" and "increasing" be interchangeable?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

**"The expansion of Willis Corp leads to ... needs of new staffs."**

A. increase

B. increased

C. increasing

D. increasingly

They said the correct answer is C but I doubted that so I immediately conducted a database search. The result is that "increased needs'' is a valid phrase. For instance:

They do not take into account your nurse-to-patient ratio even for the **increased needs** of care for those patients. ([Source](https://www.nj.com/salem/2020/06/hospital-nurses-picket-over-contract-impasse-coronavirus-concerns.html))

When state governments are faced with reduced tax revenues and **increased needs** in health care and other essential areas, it's difficult to allocate funding. ([Source](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2020/06/24/coronavirus-pandemic-worsened-higher-eds-biggest-challenges-new-survey-shows))

Her staff is trying to meet the **increased needs** while the center's budget tanks. ([Source](https://www.denverpost.com/2020/06/28/covid-colorado-budget-human-cost/))

But another thought was simply that increased spending **led to increased needs** for cash. ([Source](https://www.newstalkzb.co.nz/news/national/1-billion-shredded-as-notes-removed-from-circulation/))

So my question is: "Can both of these two adjectives ("increased" and "increasing") be interchangeable? If not, what is the difference between them? I really need your help.

Comment: B and C may both be used here, but convey different meanings. 'We have increased needs' means 'we have greater needs [than we had at some stated or inferrable time]' whereas 'we have increasing needs' means 'Our needs keep increasing'.

Comment: Staff is an uncountable noun.

Comment: @marcellothearcane _Staff_ is certainly not uncountable, at least not according to the American Heritage Dictionary, or its widespread plural usage in both the Corpus of Contemporary and Historical American English.

Comment: @DW256 according to lexico, it is the plural and singular form: https://www.lexico.com/definition/staff. "There are lots of staffs at the shop" sounds weird to my ears.  (Maybe it should be 'staves'?)